# "Missing vtable" for destructor, but destructor is defined

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, destructor, vtable

I have a class:

```
class Optimizer {
    public:
        Optimizer(mongoc_client_t *dbClient, std::string strategyName, std::string symbol, int group);
        virtual ~Optimizer() = 0;
```

and its implementation:

```
#include "optimizers/optimizer.h"

Optimizer::Optimizer(mongoc_client_t *dbClient, std::string strategyName, std::string symbol, int group) {
    // ...
}

Optimizer::~Optimizer() {
    free(data);
}
```

But I get the following error seemingly related to the destructor being undefined:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "typeinfo for Optimizer", referenced from:
      typeinfo for ReversalsOptimizer in reversalsOptimizer.o
  "vtable for Optimizer", referenced from:
      Optimizer::Optimizer(_mongoc_client_t*, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, int) in optimizer.o
      Optimizer::~Optimizer() in optimizer.o
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [prepareData] Error 1
```

What am I doing wrong? The full header definition is [here](https://github.com/chaddjohnson/forex-backtesting/blob/cpp/include/optimizers/optimizer.h) and the implementation is [here](https://github.com/chaddjohnson/forex-backtesting/blob/cpp/lib/optimizers/optimizer.cpp).

I have also tried making the destructor non-virtual, but it does not help.

Comment: So you made it pure virtual and provided an implementation?

Comment: Please edit your post and include a [mcve].

Comment: I saw in other StackOverflow posts that that's acceptable. But again, I also tried making it non-pure virtual.

Comment: Well, either you're trying to instantiate an abstract base class or this isn't all of your code because [it works fine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0b6a2ff91d30d0eb)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is exactly what the error message says:

> NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.

Specifically, you declared and called but never defined this function:

```
    virtual void prepareStudies();
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that making the other virtual functions in the Optimizer class be pure virtual functions solved the problem.